# Convert string representation of hex to hex

Tags: php

I would like to convert in php, a string to hex.

```
$bin = stringToHex("0x2022800");
```

further down the road I want to nice stuff such as:

```
for ($x = 5; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    if ($bin & (1<<$x)) {
        echo $x . " = 1 ";
    }else{
  echo $x . " = 0 ";
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work unfortunately.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: bin2hex may be?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean, you can't really convert a string representation of hex to hex, because PHP doesn't have a hex type.

If you [declare a variable using hex notatation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax) (`$hex = 0x2022800;`) , you'll get an int (33695744).

If you're starting with a string, you can use `hexdec` to get the int.

```
$int = hexdec('0x2022800');
```

If you're wanting to do bitwise operations on the result, that should get you what you need.